# Trying to hide image in dialog when mouseover another

Tags: image, jquery-ui, dialog, mouseevent

I am fast realising that coding jquery inside a dialog doesn't follow quite the same syntax as in the parent DOC . That is why my code has .live("mouseover"... instead of .mouseover(... and working that out took ages.
I have two images side by side reduced to 40% of their full size to fit inside the ajax-sourced form that is displayed in the dialog. Each has an id and my code happily expands each image individually when the cursor goes over it. I want to hide the other one when that happens and restore status quo on mouseout so the form isn't messed up. The mouseout gets me to status quo but mouseover does not hide the other image.

```
    $('#cadovr').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css('position', 'relative').height("100%").width("100%");
    $('#cadet').hide();
    }).live('mouseout',function() { 
    $(this).css('position', 'relative').height( "40%").width("40%");
    $('#cadet').show();
});
$('#cadet').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css('position', 'relative').height("100%").width("100%");
    $('#cadovr').hide();
    }).live('mouseout',function() { 
    $(this).css('position', 'relative').height( "40%").width("40%");
    $('#cadovr').show();
});
```

And has anyone a clue why I have to use .live in a dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mouseover` try using `mouseenter`

I have seen this working, thought I don't know why.

As for `.live` , Rab Nawaz has explained it well.